# Linechart point is bit off when hiding x domain intervals

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3js with lineChart graph,

My dataset contains timestamps and values for 24 hour view, each point at xx:30,
example:
`(00:30 - val_X, 01:30 - val_Y, 02:30 - val_Z, ...,23:30 - val_W)`

```js
[{"values":[{"x":1471552200000,"y":64262.58061338499},{"x":1471555800000,"y":62678.866737321965},{"x":1471559400000,"y":61750.00767023745},{"x":1471563000000,"y":61326.61449656117},{"x":1471566600000,"y":60561.389682317065},{"x":1471570200000,"y":60144.93124866629},{"x":1471573800000,"y":59785.83442165563},{"x":1471577400000,"y":69062.50859207465},{"x":1471581000000,"y":75910.99616145018},{"x":1471584600000,"y":75444.86937388242},{"x":1471588200000,"y":74308.98109650609},{"x":1471591800000,"y":73645.18914600794},{"x":1471595400000,"y":72899.18083184483},{"x":1471599000000,"y":72500.14363895029},{"x":1471602600000,"y":71881.80897423408},{"x":1471606200000,"y":71608.16164435333},{"x":1471609800000,"y":71560.75929676845},{"x":1471613400000,"y":71693.39707357567},{"x":1471617000000,"y":71662.43123936957},{"x":1471620600000,"y":70112.4723063366},{"x":1471624200000,"y":67639.43208386854},{"x":1471627800000,"y":65567.79922797237},{"x":1471631400000,"y":64098.448319984534},{"x":1471635000000,"y":62591.10055950839},{"x":1471638600000,"y":61341.82034098393},{"x":1471642200000,"y":60428.577018083095}],"key":"System Score","color":"#325c80","area":true}]
```

When I display it on a lineChart graph I see x domain from 00:30 to 23:30, I wanted to present 00:00 - 23:59, so I added 23:30 the previous day and 00:30 the next day and then I set the xDomain to [00:00, 23:59], However, the points are a bit off from its correct location althought the data is correct.
Is there anoter way to solve that problem?

[image]

Graph init:

```js
    nv.addGraph(function() {
      score_graph = nv.models.lineChart()
      .xScale(d3.time.scale())
      .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
      .showLegend(false)
      ;

      score_graph.xAxis
      .axisLabel('')
      ;

      score_graph.yAxis
      .axisLabel('y axis')
      .ticks(5)
      .tickFormat(d3.format('.3s'))
      ;

      return score_graph;
    });
```

Graph update data:
startTime is 00:00 and endTime is 23:59 of same day, 
dataset has also 23:30 of previous day and 00:30 of next day points

```js
var tooltip_obj = score_graph.interactiveLayer.tooltip;

        tooltip_obj.headerFormatter(function(d, i) {
          return graphLocales.timeFormat(time_format)(new Date(+d));
        });
        score_graph.xAxis
        .tickFormat( function(d) { return graphLocales.timeFormat(time_format)(new Date(+d)); } );

        var line_chart_data = d3.select('#score-history-block svg').datum(parsed_data_system);
        var y_max = d3.max(parsed_data_system[0].values, function(d) { return +d.y; }) * 1.2;
        if (y_max < 100) y_max = 100;
        score_graph.yDomain([0, y_max] );
        score_graph.xDomain([startTime.toDate(), endTime.toDate()]);

        line_chart_data.transition().duration(500)
        .call(score_graph)
        ;
```

Comment: Share how you have done that. Or possible provide a fiddle that produces that issue.

Comment: @AdnanUmer I've added code. thanks for fast comment!